# Spring bean not identified with @Repository annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have written a sample spring boot application and it is failing to run with message

`
Description:
Field customerRepository in com.hibernatetutorial.service.CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.hibernatetutorial.repository.CustomerRepository' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.hibernatetutorial.repository.CustomerRepository' in your configuration.`

I have a @Repository annotation on CustomerRepository class and it's package is the there in base package scanning.

Below is configuration

```
   @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.hibernatetutorial")
public class HibernateTutorialApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateTutorialApplication.class, args);

    }

}

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, UUID>{

}

@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

}
```

Customer entity is annotated with @Entity. Any suggestion if I miss anything

Comment: Is there a reason you specify a @ComponentScan manually? Are these classes in differing packages?

Comment: Yes they are in their respective packages like service, repository, model etc.. I have removed componentscan and replaced it with SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.hibernatetutorial"}) as SpringBootApplication will also takes care of component scan but still the error is ther

Comment: When you attempted to use @EnableJpaRepositories did you specify the exact package like you did with the component scan?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify any package when I tried @EnableJpaRepositories. Do I have to put package info there in that annotation?

Comment: Yes, you specify the basePackages for it to scan like with @ComponentScan.

Comment: Ok finally adding @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.hibernatetutorial.*") fixed the issue. Not sure why this needs to be added when documentation says SpringBootApplication will take care

Comment: The Application  only scans things in the same package as itself, which could be made more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of JpaRepository you need to add one of the following to your Application:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` for Spring Boot to figure it out itself or

`@EnableJpaRespositories(basePackageScan="com.example")` to specify it yourself

[For more information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-spring-data-repositories)

Comment: I tried both but the error didn't go away. As per documentation "The SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes:" Not sure if still we need to add.

Comment: My mistake, I had to do this because I had a separated configuration specified outside of the SpringBootApplication itself in my most recent spring app.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify your CustomerRepository and CustomerServiceImpl Java files are under the same packege com.hibernatetutorial.

Comment: They are not in same package but that is why I put base package scanning as (scanBasePackages={"com.hibernatetutorial"}). Here com.hibernatetutorial is part of entire package assuming it will scan all the package with starting com.hibernatetutorial

Comment: @arjun Okkay.If both files are under the base package com.hibernatetutorial.Then it should work with the ComponentScan("com.hibernatetutorial.*") annottation.

Comment: I tried ("com.hibernatetutorial.*") after I realized I have to add * but still it didn't work. It was working when I added EnableJpaRepository with base package as ("com.hibernatetutorial.*").